# How to select all checkbox in handsontable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Does anyone know how to select(check) all the check boxes in row of handsontable by checking the first check box of a particular row. I tried all the possible options to get it done but I,m not able to do it by any means.

Here is the code,

```
  function getCarData() {
    return [
      { available: true,available2: true,available3: true, comesInBlack: 'yes'},
      {available: false,available2: true,available3: true,available3: true, comesInBlack: 'yes'},
      { available: true,available2: true,available3: true, comesInBlack: 'no'},
      {available: false,available2: true,available3: true, comesInBlack: 'yes'},
      { available: false,available2: true,available3: true, comesInBlack: 'no'}
    ];
  }

  var example1 = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot1;

  hot1 = new Handsontable(example1, {
    data: getCarData(),
    colHeaders: ['Available','Available2','Available3'],
    columns: [

      {
        data: 'available',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },{
        data: 'available2',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },{
        data: 'available3',
        type: 'checkbox'
      }
    ]
  });
```

Here is the jsfiddle link
jsfiddle.net/mq5on8qf

Comment: your fiddle seems incomplete... theres nothing to check in the div. Can you complete the html and then we can help you

Comment: Link non-SSL fiddle to prevent security errors: http://jsfiddle.net/mq5on8qf/

Comment: @Simon Price, As myf suggested I've changed the link,can you please check now?

Comment: so if you click on the checkbox at cell 0,0 you want all columns on that row to be checked/unchecked as well?

Comment: @ZekeDroid, Yes excatly.That is what I wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is add an `afterChange` event which checks for a change on the first column, and if so, sets the values of the columns on that row to the new value. Here is an implementation of such an event:

```
afterChange: function (changes, source) {
    var change = changes[0]; // [row, prop, oldVal, newVal]
    var row = change[0];
    var data = this.getData(); // reference to data object
    var newVal = change[3];
    var col = change[1];

    // conditional on first row
    if (col === 'available') {
        data[row].available2 = newVal;
        data[row].available3 = newVal;
    }
    this.render(); // render after making changes to data
}
```

And [here is your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mq5on8qf/1/) with it applied.

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)